# How to Send emails to multiple recipients in PHP

Tags: php

I need to send my forms to multiple recipients, but I can't figure it out which line I need to edit. Please see below. I appreciate your help.

I already tried adding more values to the emailto, but I can't get it to work.

I need to send my forms to multiple recipients, but I can't figure it out which line I need to edit. Please see below. I appreciate your help.

I already tried adding more values to the emailto, but I can't get it to work.

```css
Hello there,

 I need to send my forms to multiple recipients, but I can't figure it out which line I need to edit. Please see below. I appreciate your help.



<?php
// Configure your Subject Prefix and Recipient here


$errors = array(); // array to hold validation errors
$data   = array(); // array to pass back data

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $subjectPrefix = $_POST['subject'];
    $privacyPolicy = $_POST['privacy-policy'];
    $emailTo = stripslashes(trim($_POST['email-to']));
    $name    = stripslashes(trim($_POST['name']));
    $email   = stripslashes(trim($_POST['email']));
    $phone   = stripslashes(trim($_POST['phone']));
    $message = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
    $spam    = $_POST['textfield'];
    $confirmMsg = $_POST['confirm'];
    $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];

    if (empty($name)) {
        $errors['name'] = 'Please fill in all required fields.';
    }

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors['email'] = 'Please fill in all required fields.';
    }

    if (empty($message)) {
        $errors['message'] = 'Please fill in all required fields.';
    }
    
    if (empty($captcha)) {
        $errors['captcha'] = 'TEST CAPTCHA';
    }

    if (empty($privacyPolicy)) {
        $errors['privacy_policy'] = 'Please fill in all required fields.';
    }

    // if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean or false
    if (!empty($errors)) {
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors']  = $errors;
    } else {
        $subject = "Message from $subjectPrefix";
        $body    = '
            <strong>Name: </strong>'.$name.'<br />
            <strong>Email: </strong>'.$email.'<br />
            <strong>Phone: </strong>'.$phone.'<br />
            <strong>Message: </strong>'.nl2br($message).'<br />
        ';

        $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.1" . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "Date: " . date('r', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']) . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "Message-ID: <" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] . md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']) . '@' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '>' . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "From: " . "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($name)."?=" . " <$email> " . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "Return-Path: $emailTo" . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "X-Originating-IP: " . $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] . PHP_EOL;


        if (empty($spam)) {
          mail($emailTo, "=?utf-8?B?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?=", $body, $headers);
        }

        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['confirmation'] = $confirmMsg;
    }

    // return all our data to an AJAX call
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Send it in the loop, or better use some mailing library like PhpMailer, or SwiftMailer which will allow you to handle mail sending in much advanced form.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It can be hard to come up with the right search terms, but please do try searching before posting a new question - there are *many* examples here showing how to do what you're asking, and the PHP docs themselves answer your question. You'll also get a better response if you take a little care writing up your question - it looks like you've copy-pasted the same text 3 times above.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate receivers by comma like

```
$to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) documentation you can use this:

```
$emailTo = $mail1 . ', ' . $mail2;
```